# "Esto sí (que) es lo que llamo X..." , "Esto sí (que) es X", "Esto sì (que) sería"...?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Un interlocutor dice la frase: "hacer algo (X) sería mágico.".
Yo quiero responder describiendo algo diferente (Y) para sugerir y destacar que Y es mágico., no X. Y ojalá decirlo de una forma muy sintética.

Habida cuenta de que Y ya ha sido descrito, tengo dudas sobre la manera correcta de expresar que Y es mágico (y que se deduzca implícitamente que es más mágico que X):

a) "Esto sí que es magia."

b) "Esto sí sería magia."

c) "Esto sí sería mágico."

d) "Esto sí que sería mágico."

e) "Esto se llama magia."

f) "Esto sí que se llama magia."

g) ¿... (alguna frase diferente)?

- *modificación* - - -

Si eligimos las siguientes formas:

1) "Eso sí sería magia."

2) "Eso sí QUE sería magia."

Cuál os parece mejor entre las dos? Con "que" o sin "que"?

Comment: Makes me think of the old joke, where the punch line is S-O-C-K-S  (eso sí que es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Eso sí [que] sería magia.**

Notas.

1. Uso el condicionial (*sería*) porque ahorita X y Y están en el nivel
   de contemplar.  (Después de una demostración, podrías decir Eso sí
   es magia.)
2. Uso "eso" en lugar de "esto" por lo mismo.
3. Uso *magia* y no *mágico* porque "magia" es un término más general;
   "mágico" me da más la idea de la varita mágica y la transformación
   de calabaza en carroza.

Otras opciones:

Eso [sí que] es lo que se llama magia.
Eso [sí que] es lo que yo llamo magia.
Eso sí lo llamo magia.
Eso sí se puede llamar magia.
Eso es lo que se llama magia.

Si te refieres a un truco que has demostrado, puedes decir

> Eso es magia.

Si estás revelando las técnicas que permiten lograr el truco, puedes decir

> Esa es la magia [de algo].  Por ejemplo "Esa es la magia del cálculo
>   diferencial."

Comment: Gracias... Pues, aplicando tus reglas 1. y 2., sería correcto decir  "Eso sí que sería magia"?

Comment: @robertalrp - sí, se puede.  Estoy dudando un poco, pero me inclino a pensar que se oye más seguro y contundente sin "que."  Ojalá participen otros usuarios.

Comment: Es decir "Eso sí sería magia"?

Comment: @robertalrp - Exacto.

Comment: gracias, esto ha sido muy útil